# Using Java `assert` Specifically for not-null Method Preconditions

Tags: java, exception, null, assert, preconditions

Yes, there are many questions and perfectly good answers dealing with the Java `assert` statement and when exceptions should be used instead. This question is about one specific use case which normally falls within the sound category of, "Never use `assert` to ensure preconditions," -- or words to that effect. So, please bear with me for a moment longer...

All Java object references can be `null` and are `null` by default. Even `enum` references can be `null` in addition to referencing only the set of values specified in the `enum` implementation. Consequently, there is a great deal of testing for `null` which must occur in most Java programs. Some of that testing consists of checking for `null` as a value returned by a given API which denotes absence, failure intended to be handled by the caller, or some other bit of state information. However, most tests for `null` are meant to fail early when an unexpected `null` is encountered. To properly "fail early" as often as possible while also using executable code to function as a self-documenting precondition, conditional tests which throw an exception may be used to check for unwanted `null` values.

But...

An unwanted `null` value will usually cause a `NullPointerException` to be thrown at some point, though it may be long after the point where the source of the `null` may be easily determined when testing or debugging an application. So, `null` values usually do not go undetected, it is just that the self-reporting of incorrect use may not be very helpful. But regardless of whether an exception arises from detection of an unexpected `null` or as a result of attempting to dereference it, the exception is almost certainly fatal or will have to be handled at a level which fully backs out whatever led to any fatal exception.

So, an unwanted, unintended `null` will eventually bite at some point in time. Testing preconditions merely moves that point, in the best case, to a point in time which may make it easier for a developer to find the source of the problem. But if explicit tests or exceptions are used to check all possible unwanted `null` values, however unlikely, that results in a great many conditional branches in the compiled code where the expected and common branch to be taken is the branch which skips the code which throws an exception.

Given all that and the nature of Java object references, it seems that `assert` statements should be preferable specifically for preconditions which preclude `null` values. In development and testing, the preconditions are enabled and aid in detecting and fixing defects. In production, fatal errors from unexpected `null` values happen later, but usually do not fail to occur -- critical code which must never under any circumstances accept a `null` value can always use an explicit test and thrown exception even if `assert` is used elsewhere. Therefore, using `assert` can limit unnecessary overhead in production code for this one, common and almost ubiquitous precondition.

Given all that, is there a sound argument against using `assert` statements for preconditions which specifically document and reject `null` values which are invalid arguments, input, or state?

Comment: Frankly, I wouldn't worry about "unnecessary overhead in production code" from doing the check all the time -- null checks are going to be so fast that it really shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman I know that is the common wisdom with a reasonably good foundation, but enough code in enough inner loops can add up to real overhead. However, I am considering a coding convention which will help in those relatively rare cases where it matters, does not hurt at all where it doesn't matter, and which is almost always a one-liner in otherwise typically verbose code in contrast to a typical three or more line coding convention for testing a condition and throwing an exception.

Comment: Let me put it another way: I wouldn't be surprised if the overhead of checking to see if an `assert` is turned on in the first place exceeded the overhead of checking if a variable was null, and checking for null and throwing an NPE should be a one-liner with Guava's `Preconditions` or JDK7's `Objects.requireNonNull` either way.

Comment: I don't know how most JVM implementations handle JIT compilation, but if the compilation does not completely omit all assertion code when generating native code, that would be a poor implementation. And, of course, omitted code produces no overhead at all. But having said that, `Objects.requireNonNull` in JDK 7 is something I did not know was available and does add something for me to consider. Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm... Looking at the source code for [`Objects.requireNonNull`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/Objects.java#Objects.requireNonNull%28java.lang.Object%29), there really isn't much it brings to the table. In fact, it will just add a bit of unneeded additional overhead if it is passed a method argument which is used directly throughout the method -- i.e. the argument value is not copied to an instance variable or a local variable as done in the code examples in the documentation. Still, thanks again for calling it to my attention.

Comment: You should realistically expect `Objects.requireNonNull` to be inlined, and for unnecessary work to be trimmed out.  I wouldn't expect it to have any measurable performance difference at all from the traditional if-then-throw.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I suspect you are correct. It's return value can also be ignored if desired making it as easy to use as any other exception-throwing precondition. So, no reason to avoid it in code which will only run on version 7+ JVMs. But then we are back to the original question, is there any good reason to not use `assert` in the case I have described? But even though that is my question, I have no argument against using exception-based preconditions if that is what someone prefers.

Answer (score 2):

I think the fact that `assert`s are disabled by default is enough to keep me from using them for anything critical.

Comment: In critical code which must fail just as soon as an unexpected `null` value is detected, I agree. However, for the common case where a developer violates a documented precondition for an API which eventually "breaks" the API, `assert` seems to be a reasonable means by which to detect a violation of the API and aid in debugging the problem during development and testing without burdening production code with "fail early" checks for improper use of an API by code which violated a precondition.

Comment: Sure, as long as they're enabled. You can programmatically check if they're enabled before you use them but I'm not sure that gets you any advantage over a plain old `if (something == null) { throw new NullPointerException("blah"); }`

Comment: Assertions should be enabled during development and testing, but if they are not, the `assert` still functions as executable documentation in the code. Any `null` value not tested because assertions are not enabled will usually cause a NullPointerException to be thrown eventually. If the developer can not track down the source of the problem right away, then they might get the incentive they need to enable assertions. Otherwise, no harm, no foul, and a bit less overhead in production...